# Error when serving npm http-server through terminal. (Error 404)

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, httpserver

I have been trying to run a local http server for my HTML files after figuring out that the problem I was having with ng-view is that chrome does not support cross origin requests due to security reasons. Hence, I downloaded the npm http-server and tried running my html code and I get the error message:

```
Starting up http-server, serving indexTemplate.html
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:8080
  http://172.27.88.21:8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
[Mon Jun 27 2016 19:48:11 GMT+0900 (KST)] "GET /" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36"
[Mon Jun 27 2016 19:48:11 GMT+0900 (KST)] "GET /" Error (404): "Not found"
```

Can anyone help me in figuring out what the problem is and how I can solve it? Any suggestions and help would be much appreciated!

Comment: So did you try to go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/indexTemplate.html`

Comment: yeah it wouldn't load

Comment: Try to run just `http-server` without `indexTemplate.html`. I just try to run `http-server` in a folder where i only have index.html and it works just fine

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that you just run the http-server in the folder and not the file. Works like a charm now.

Comment: Same error on Heroku

Answer (score 16):

Try to run just `http-server` without `indexTemplate.html` as a parameter, in the folder where you only have `indexTemplate.html` and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 9):

While you are serving Please make sure you are serving an entire folder and not a file. 
For example : NOT RIGHT

`http-server "/home/ubuntu/sandbox/basicserver/index.html"`

But RIGHT:

`http-server "/home/ubuntu/sandbox/basicserver/"`

Comment: this is the perfect answer

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue with an angular app, the problem was I was running the command at the src folder

```
PS D:\Pub Sub Kafka\App\NotificationApp\angular-pwa-app\src> http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist/angular-pwa-app
```

I got the error

> This localhost page can’t be found

Then I went one folder up where the dist folder located then ran the command

```
PS D:\Pub Sub Kafka\App\NotificationApp\angular-pwa-app> http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist/angular-pwa-app
```

and it rendered the page on http://localhost:8080/